# Dompdf how do i make a button to print pdf

Tags: php, html, button, dompdf

How do i make a button? if i open the page right now, it wont show the html but instantly convert & download the pdf. I want a button to make it only convert & download when you press for example the submit button.

This is my code.

```
<?php
    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");        
    ob_start();
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite templating system.</p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

I am a newbie in this but i guess it have somthing to do with the

```
<?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

part.
I use Dompdf for this.

Answer (score 0):

One option for you would be to create another php file which generates the desired content into a pdf, and link to that php file where you want to put your download option.

```
view.html <- This is the page where your link is at

    <a href="pdfGen.php"> convert & download </a>

pdfGen.php

<?php
    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");        
    ob_start();
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite templating system.</p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an example? I am pretty new to all this :p
Thanks for the fast respondse btw

Comment: Doesn't work. :/
It doesn't recognize the  PHP ob_start(); from the original file

Comment: You have to put your content (to be generated as a pdf) between `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();`, or find another way to generate content and supply it to the `$dompdf->load_html();` method.

Comment: If i use it like :

<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

      ob_start();
?>
  <html><body>
  <p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite 
  templating system.</p>
<form action="pdfGen.php">
    <input type="submit" value="PDF">
</form>
  </body></html>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();

?> my page wont load the html code. For some reason it only shows a blanc page

Comment: The `ob_start();` opens a buffer, to store all the output, and `ob_get_clean();` closes this buffer and returns the captured content for you to save it in a variable (`$html = ob_get_clean();`). Nothing will show up from the content between those two methods. The dompdf in the example captures the content, passes it to the dompdf class with the `load_html();` function, and sends the resulting pdf file to the browser (`stream();`). What you're doing is storing the content what you want to want to show to the user, and try to send that to the user.